# How to scroll to down to multiple rows of dynamic controls in panel in c sharp

Tags: c#, winforms, scroll, panel

I have an application where i will need to add dynamic controls to a panel
based on the value of a number entered in a textbox.
E.g 5 means i generate 5 rows of the controls on the button click event.
The issue is that when a large number (for example 50) is entered,although
50 rows of dynamic controls are added,i am unable to scroll down to each 
of the 50 rows.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int inputNumber = Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        int wid=0;
            int  hgt = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= inputNumber; i++)
        {
            //Create a new label and text box
            Label labelInput = new Label();
            TextBox textBoxNewInput = new TextBox();
            ComboBox cb = new ComboBox();
            //Initialize label's property
            labelInput.Text = "Input " + i;
            labelInput.Location = new Point(30, textBox1.Bottom + (i * 30));
            labelInput.AutoSize = true;

            //Initialize textBoxes Property
            textBoxNewInput.Location = new Point(labelInput.Width, labelInput.Top - 3);
            cb.Location = new Point(textBoxNewInput.Width + labelInput.Width + 10, textBoxNewInput.Top);
            hgt += textBoxNewInput.Top;

            //Add the labels and text box to the form
            panel1.Controls.Add(labelInput);
            panel1.Controls.Add(textBoxNewInput);
            panel1.Controls.Add(cb);

        }
        ScrollBar vScrollBar1 = new VScrollBar();
      vScrollBar1.Dock = DockStyle.Right;
       vScrollBar1.Scroll += (mender, f) => { panel1.VerticalScroll.Value = vScrollBar1.Value; };
        panel1.Controls.Add(vScrollBar1);
        Controls.Add(panel1);
       }
```

How can i be able to scroll from row 1 to row 100 or row 500 as the case may be?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you're not using a [grid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163813.aspx)? Manipulate the grid instead.

Comment: True. Typically they have steep learning curves - but it's worth it. The problem is because probably your next question is going to be "My client don't want 500 rows in one go. How do I implement paging?"

:P

Comment: I have decided to go with the gridview ,it seems that it will be easier in the long run, with the DataGridViewComboBoxColumn,and the  DataGridViewTextBoxColumn.

Answer (score 0):

I did further research and i got the answer:

I removed these lines of code

```
       ScrollBar vScrollBar1 = new VScrollBar();
      vScrollBar1.Dock = DockStyle.Right;
      vScrollBar1.Scroll += (mender, f) => { panel1.VerticalScroll.Value = vScrollBar1.Value; };
        panel1.Controls.Add(vScrollBar1);
```

And i just set the autoscroll property

```
     panel1.AutoScroll=true;
```

Works fine